# Mujoco fatal error, How can I set Xlib.h to my PATH?

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, gcc, mujoco

I'm very new in Linux Terminal
As I know if I edit (nano ~/.bashrc) bashrc and do export path
then all files will connect with exported PATH
So I did
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmTIP.png)
My bashrc

and did source ~/.bashrc
after that I write the Mujoco
my command was$python3 -c "import mujoco_py"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKW3W.png)
FATAL EERror

And then I get fatal error.So I checked that directory
Cute header files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsFK4.png)
There are Xlib.h (2,3)
I'm so confuse about this matter, How can I solve it?

(I had edit all files' directory to
#include /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h ...
this had worked but This is not a good idea my think
and after that I got GL directory error again .. )